# maximum likelihood estimation in r

Tags: r

For this non-linear equation

```
y = a*(1-exp(-(x/b)))^c
```

by using **least square** estimated values for the parameters are obtained and

```
x <- c(3, 33, 146, 227, 342, 351, 353, 444, 556, 571, 709, 759, 836, 
860, 968, 1056, 1726, 1846, 1872, 1986, 2311, 2366, 2608, 2676, 
3098, 3278, 3288, 4434, 5034, 5049, 5085, 5089, 5089, 5097, 5324, 
5389, 5565, 5623, 6080, 6380, 6477, 6740, 7192, 7447, 7644, 7837, 
7843, 7922, 8738, 10089, 10237, 10258, 10491, 10625, 10982, 11175, 
11411, 11442, 11811, 12559, 12559, 12791, 13121, 13486, 14708, 
15251, 15261, 15277, 15806, 16185, 16229, 16358, 17168, 17458, 
17758, 18287, 18568, 18728, 19556, 20567, 21012, 21308, 23063, 
24127, 25910, 26770, 27753, 28460, 28493, 29361, 30085, 32408, 
35338, 36799, 37642, 37654, 37915, 39715, 40580, 42015, 42045, 
42188, 42296, 42296, 45406, 46653, 47596, 48296, 49171, 49416, 
50145, 52042, 52489, 52875, 53321, 53443, 54433, 55381, 56463, 
56485, 56560, 57042, 62551, 62651, 62661, 63732, 64103, 64893, 
71043, 74364, 75409, 76057, 81542, 82702, 84566, 88682)

y <- c(1:136)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

fit <- nls(y ~ a*(1-exp(-x/b))^c, data=df, start = list( a=100,b=1000,c=0.5),  
     algorithm="port",lower=list(a=100,b=100,c=0.5),upper=list(a=200,b=10000,c=2))
```

**How to do this using Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) for this non-linear equation ?**

Comment: What is wrong with nls?

Comment: my project is to obtain estimated parameters from both least square and mle and justify which is best .. method

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on CrossValidated.com

Comment: You'll need to calculate the MLE by hand, then fit that to the dataset.

Comment: i did few calculations but i don't know how to apply them.. and obtain the parameter values..

Comment: definitely belongs on crossvalidated.com.  Using MLE means you have to make some distributional assumptions.  If you assume your responses are independent Normal with homogeneous variance and mean equal to your nonlinear expression then the ML and least-squares criteria will give the same answers.